# Resistor in parallel across a capacitor

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, capacitor

I was working through a problem involving two cascaded integrating op amps with feedback resistors with a DC step function as input. The book asks for the current flowing from the capacitor in the second op amp  at t=0.5s when the voltage across the capacitor is 1.55V. In the solution the author redraws the circuit but leaves out the 5M ohm resistor in parallel with the capacitor and solves for the current using KVL at the node between the 400k resistor and the capacitor (the voltage is zero at the node because of ideal op amp constraints).Why would he ignore the resistor when finding the current? Would there really be no current flowing through the resistor across the capacitor? I've attached the redrawn circuit from the book.[image: Redrawn op amp circuit without 5M resistor in parallel with capacitor]

Comment: I don't see any opamp,in your schematic. Where is it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a voltage-controlled inverting integrator with a fixed upper DC gain of -5M/0.4M = -12.5 but the present voltage ratio is ~ -3 so the voltage ramp is still fairly linear.

So what input ratio controls the current into the virtual ground?

Now you can answer your own questions.